# Got the error when Rendering the material ui autocomplete

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am using react v17.0.2m,react-redux v7.2.6, @reduxjs/toolkit v1.7.2

When I am rending a page in the react. It is showing that the error related to the Autocomplete component of the Material-UI.Along with the typescript I found it difficult to solve the problem

Please Help me how to solve this problem.

Here is my code

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Card from "@mui/material/Card";
import CardActions from "@mui/material/CardActions";
import CardContent from "@mui/material/CardContent";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import { IInterview } from "../../store/CreateInterview.slice";
import { Chip } from "@mui/material";
import { useAppDispatch } from "../../store/hooks";
import { editInterview } from "../../services/CreateInterview.service";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { LoadingButton } from "@mui/lab";
import ModeEditIcon from "@mui/icons-material/ModeEdit";
const InterviewCard: React.FC<{
  interview: Omit<IInterview, "questions">;
}> = ({ interview: { _id, title, tags } }) => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const disptach = useAppDispatch();
  const handleEdit = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    const response = await disptach(editInterview(_id));
    if (response.payload) {
      navigate("/createInterview");
    }
    setLoading(false);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(false);
  }, []);

  return (
    <Card sx={{ maxWidth: "70%", margin: "20px auto" }}>
      <CardContent>
        <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="div">
          {title}
        </Typography>
        <RenderTags tags={tags} />
      </CardContent>
      <CardActions>
        <LoadingButton
          variant="contained"
          color="success"
          loading={loading}
          loadingPosition="start"
          onClick={handleEdit}
          startIcon={<ModeEditIcon />}
        >
          Edit
        </LoadingButton>
        <Button size="small">Learn More</Button>
      </CardActions>
    </Card>
  );
};

const RenderTags: React.FC<{ tags: IInterview["tags"] }> = ({ tags }) => {
  return (
    <>
      {tags.map(({ _id, title }) => {
        return (
          <Chip
            label={`${title}`}
            variant="outlined"
            key={_id}
            style={{ marginRight: "10px", marginTop: "5px" }}
          />
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
};

export default InterviewCard;
```

Error in browser console

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This warning was introduced since React V16.3.0.

If you are using functional components you could wrap the setState call into useEffect.

Code that does not work:

```
const HomePage = (props) => {
    
  props.setAuthenticated(true);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    props.setSearchTerm(e.target.value.toLowerCase());
  };

  return (
    <div key={props.restInfo.storeId} className="container-fluid">
      <ProductList searchResults={props.searchResults} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Now you can change it to:

```
const HomePage = (props) => {
  // trigger on component mount
  useEffect(() => {
    props.setAuthenticated(true);
  }, []);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    props.setSearchTerm(e.target.value.toLowerCase());
  };

  return (
    <div key={props.restInfo.storeId} className="container-fluid">
      <ProductList searchResults={props.searchResults} />
    </div>
  );
};
```